# Laplace equation and a result about its solution

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-derivative, harmonic-functions

Let $u: \mathbb{R}^{2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{2}$, $u \in C^2(D)$ where $D$ is the unitary disc, if $u$ satisfies the Laplace equation on $D$, i. e.

$\displaystyle\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2} = 0$

I want to know if I always can find another solution $v$, $v \in C^{2}(D)$  such that $u$ and $v$ satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations, i. e.

$$\displaystyle\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}$$

and

$$\displaystyle\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} = -\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}$$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_conjugate

Comment: You can circumvent the need for Cauchy-Riemann and just separate variables, based on some boundary conditions.